# Different Sorting methods and random

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

I am working with `random` and `sorting` methods. So far I have the linear method working.  I am trying to implement a way that will let the user decide which type of sorting to use such as `linear`, `bubble`, `index`, etc.  So I have added `textBox7` with the label `Key` and `button3` which the user clicks until the find their desired sorting method.  When Key`textbox7` has a value chosen then the sort array `button2` will execute that particular sorting method. How can I execute a particular sorting method based on the `Key` value? Below is picture of how I have the windows form set up

**CODE**

```
namespace sortmachine
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }


        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();


        Random r = new Random();

        private int size = 0;
        private int max = 0;
        private int ops = 0;
        private int[] ar1;
        private int[] ar2;
        private int[] ar3;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                size = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
                max = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
                string s = "";

                ar1 = new int[size];
                ar2 = new int[size];
                ar3 = new int[size];

                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                {
                    int n = r.Next(0, max);
                    ar1[i] = n;
                    ar2[i] = ar1[i];
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                {
                    s += ar1[i].ToString() + " ";
                }
                listView1.Items.Add(s);
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please input information");
            }

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int min = max;
            int n = 0;
            string s="";

            sw.Start();

            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                {
                    if (min > ar2[i])
                    {
                        min = ar2[i];
                        n = i;
                        ops++;
                    }
                    if (min < ar2[i])
                    {
                        ops++;
                    }

                }
                ar2[n]=max;
                ar3[j] = min;
                min = max;
                s += ar3[j] + " ";
            }

            TimeSpan x = sw.Elapsed;
            textBox5.Text = x.ToString();

                listView2.Items.Add(s);
                listView2.Text = s;
                textBox6.Text = Convert.ToString(ops);
                if (checkBox1.Checked==true)
                {
                    textBox1.AppendText(s+Environment.NewLine);
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                {
                    ar2[i] = ar1[i];
                }
                ops = 0;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Separate the sorting from the UI. Each sort method should have a signature like `List<int> BubbleSort (List<int> input)` - it could even be extracted further into an Interface, but this should be "much cleaner" - and the sort functions should *not* use any member variables: only the input parameter and some local variables. The UI just gets the stuff to sort and feeds it to the sort function and then takes the results of the sort and shoves it back into the UI. The various algorithms can be found on Wikipedia, etc.

Comment: Also, use new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode()) to seed your random.

Comment: Charlie, if you need any additional help, just let me know. I work with winforms a bit and can always hook you up with some knowledge. Or if you want the project from my answer, that too :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Id give this a go as it implements what others were suggesting:

Inside each if conditional you can perform your own logic per sort type. As you can see I have a sorting option selected from the combobox with other buttons to add numbers to my list for sorting and a control to display the results.

The code is as follows in the Screenshot:

```
if(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Linear")
{
}
else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Bubble")
{            
}
else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Index")
{
}
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a combobox or DropDownList to store the sorting options and use its SelectedText property to determine which sort method to use when the user click sort.

Just drag a combobox onto your form.  Then add items to it be clicking edit items and filling in the values.

Then all you do in code is write something like.

```
string sortOption = comboBox1.SelectedText;
```

Comment: +1 Could you show me implementing this with a comboBox or DropDownList?

Answer (score 0):

How about using `RadioButton` List to choose between the sorting options to determine the Sorting required by the User instead of Key Value approach.

Just place the `RadioButtons` inside some `GroupBox` that will allow only one `RadioButton` selection at a time and upon Sort button click, you can check for the `Checked` property of each `RadioButton` to apply the sorting.

```
if (rdoBtnQuick.Checked)
    // Apply Quick Sort
else if (rdoBtnSelection.Checked)
    // Apply Selection Sort
else if (rdoBtnBubble.Checked)
    // Apply Bubble Sort
//...
```